# how to activate __str__ dunder method using instance and fix error:"__str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)"

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I have been trying to create a rational class, and add a `__str__`dunder method to return the p(numerator), divided by the q(denominator). when i try to print the object rational_1, it only gives me the output of the **init** method and doesn't return the `__str__` dunder method at all.  So i tried to use print instead of return, but it raises an error:`"__str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)"`. How do i print the str and also not raise an error? thanks!

```
import math
class Rational:
    def __init__(self,p,q):
        self.p=p
        self.q=q
    def __str__(self):
        self.great_dev=math.gcd(self.p,self.q)
        self.p=self.p/self.great_dev
        self.q=self.q/self.great_dev
        print ("{self.p}/{self.q}".format(self=self))
rational_1=Rational(3,60)
print(rational_1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, you need to `return` the new string representation of the class instance you created in the overriden `__str__` dunder method.

```
def __str__(self):
    self.great_dev=math.gcd(self.p,self.q)
    self.p=self.p/self.great_dev
    self.q=self.q/self.great_dev
    # return the updated string representation
    return "{self.p}/{self.q}".format(self=self)
```

Then the code will expected and the output will be `1.0/20.0`

Comment: There was an error because I used print, instead of return? when i used return nothing was printed. could i have printed it correctly without the f string? also, thank you so much for your answer sir, it really helped!

Comment: i have python 3, the first answer was great, thank you! i just wanted to understand better, so return "{self.p}/{self.q}".format(self=self) works on the older version?